# Parsing through all folders in a directory

Tags: stata

I am working with Stata and am a beginner. I have a question regarding grabbing folder names. I have a directory, \Test\abc, that has the following folders like this:

```
Q100
Q101
Q102
....
```

I would like to go into each folder, Q* (where * denotes anything after the Q), find a file named "filenameQ*", do something, and then send the output back to \Test\abc. The following code shows the idea of what I want to do, where varlist Q* denotes the array of all the folders in the directory that begin with Q. However, folder names aren't variables, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
cd "\\Test\abc"
foreach x of varlist Q* /* FOLDER NAMES */ { 
    cd "`x'"
    use "filename`x'" 
    display something and send it back to directory "\\Test\abc"
    cd ..
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a user-written command called `folders` that will store the names of folders in a local r(folders). There is another command called `fs` that does the same for files.

Here's an example of how you might do this (given your ordering constraint in the comments):

```
capture ssc install fs, replace
cd "~/Desktop/Test/abc"

/* Get a list of years to loop over by stripping out Q[0-9] stubs, quotes, and de-dupeing */
folders Q*
local years=ustrregexra(`"`=ustrregexra(`"`r(folders)'"',"Q[0-9]","")'"',`"""',"")
local years: list uniq years

foreach y of local years {
    folders Q?`y'

    foreach d in `r(folders)' {
    cd "`d'"
    fs filename*
        foreach f in `r(files)' {
            ls `f'
        }
    cd ..
    }   
}
```

Comment: `folders` and `fs` are in the same package `fs` so one install is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you! One other question -- how would I sort the content of folders, assuming the Q* are out of order?

Comment: @Justin Both `folders` and `fs` lists things in ascending order. How would you want to sort these?

Comment: So the folders/files have the following suffix: Q[0-9](Year). The year must be in ascending order. So the above code sorts them such that it ends up like Q11995, Q11996, Q1997, etc -- instead, I would like Q11995, Q21995, ... Q91995, Q21996

Comment: @Justin I edited the code to take the ordering constraint into account. You should edit the question to include that key information.

Comment: @Dimitriy My apologies I thought I had responded to this but realized I didn't. Thank you for your help! 

I am also wondering whether it is possible to reset the counter in the foreach loop. For instance, is it possible to "go back one folder?"

Comment: @Justin I am not entirely sure what that means.You can use a forvalues loop that loops over the elements of the r(folders) local, so at the kth iterations the previous folder would just mean the (k-1)th element if that local. I think you should ask another question if you can't figure out how to do that on your own.

Comment: Ah understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Stata has a set of extended functions for macros. See `help extended_fcn` as a reference. One of these extended functions helps you grab names of folders and files.

To get a list of folders stored in a local macro named `folderList`, use

```
local folderList : dir "<PATH1>" dirs "Q*"
```

where

```
<PATH1>
```

is the path to the folder containing the folders of interest. You can similarly pull file names in a folder using

```
local fileList : dir "<PATH2>" files "filenameQ*"
```

Here is the basic idea using two `foreach` loops:

```
* get the list of folders
local path1 <PATH1>
local folderList : dir "`path1'" dirs "Q*"

* loop through folders
foreach folder of local folderList {
  * get list of files
  local fileList : dir "`path1'/`folder'" files "filenameQ*"

  * loop through files
  foreach file of local fileList {
    * do stuff to file
    use `file'
    ** do more stuff
  }
}
```

I removed the `cd` part as it is often preferable to keep the same working directory in order to specify the same output paths regardless of the location of the current file of interest.